# deploy a hyperledger composer network bna file on a hyperledger fabric network that has been built separately

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger-composer

How do I deploy a hyperledger composer network bna file on a hyperledger fabric network that has been built separately, I have built a network bna successfully now I am facing very weird issues, if anyone could suggest something best please go on?

Comment: I have already tried all stuff provided on fabirc read the docs and composer read the docs, so please give out custom deploy suggestions, Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you provide an example of what commands you have tried, what your connection profile looks like and what your fabric setup is that you are trying to deploy to ? Also what are the errors you are getting ?